# Setting up LaTeX compiling protocol in VSCode (LaTeX-Workshop)

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, compiling

I apologize if this is not really a question, but more of a call for help because I'm really lost in how to use LaTeX command tools and all that sort of stuff and I don't really have time to investigate it deeply on my own.

I am using the VSCode extension *LaTeX Workshop* to work here, and I was trying to have a setup like the following:

```
subject/ # parent folder
  |-- assets/ # images stored here
  |-- books/
  |   |-- bookone/
  |   |   |-- bookone.bib
  |   |-- booktwo/
  |   |   |-- booktwo.bib
  |-- source/
  |   |-- dist/ # here should go all the auxiliary files including synctex and fls
  |   |-- partone/
  |   |   |-- partone.tex
  |   |-- parttwo/
  |   |   |-- parttwo.tex
  |-- partone.pdf
  |-- parttwo.pdf
```

I tried messing with `"latex-workshop.latex.outDir"` and `"latex-workshop.latex.tools"` settings but apparently I also have to use recipes for command lines and I really have no idea on how to use them. I'm also getting errors on finding `.bib` files when I change `outDir`, etc.

Please help.

Comment: the handling of folders for auxiliary files depends on the underlying tex-system (miktex or texlive). But like David I wouldn't recommend to use such a folder - it makes life unnessary difficult.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will consider leaving it be, then. But I'd very much like having things tidied up. I'll see if the owner of the plugin says something about this.

Comment: If you search this site for `aux-directory` and `output-directory` you will see that none of the expert use or recommend them. You only get problems as many of the output files are actually input file for the next compilation or other tools.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what I might do then is activate the feature that automatically cleans all those files once the `.pdf` file is created, is that a bad idea?

Comment: well normally you slow down the next compilation if you always clean up. Also why bother? The important thing is not to get rid of these files, but to backup the main files. So setup some git.

Comment: If "tiding up" is the only reason you are trying to do this, have a look at `ltx2any` (https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any) instead